# Vuejs - Firebase/firestore spams network requests

Tags: firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

I just tried implementing firebase with a vue-project.
Currently all I have setup is a connection to firebase and I'm exposing the firestore to a component.
As soon as I import and use my database, my network tab starts spamming tokens until my "quota obligation is reached". Does anyone know why this happens?
I've got a firebase.js file setup as follows:

```
import firebase from 'firebase';
const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(config);
const db = firebaseApp.firestore();
export default db;
```

And then in a component i import db from this file, no matter what I do, even if I just console.log(db) in mounted it starts spamming these requests. Whenever my quota obligations is reached I get a 400 returned in the console. What am I doing wrong here? As soon as i initialize the firestore this happens, no matter if I do it in the firebase.js file or locally in a component.

[image]

Comment: Your firebase setup looks wrong (or at least very old). [This is what it _should_ look like](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#using-module-bundlers). Also, what are you doing with `db` in your component? Please show that code

Comment: Not sure what you mean by wrong or very old. If you read the article you linked to, I am doing pretty much exactly what they want you to do. The only exception is that I'm using a require instead of an import, and that I'm storing references in variables (like "const firebaseApp = ....", which also is how the guide does it when using firestore).
Like I wrote in my post, it does not matter what I do with db. It's a reference to the firestore, so I can use it to query collections of data. I get this weird behavior when I create the reference to firestore (firebaseApp.firestore())

Comment: The article I linked shows `import * as firebase from "firebase/app"` and `import "firebase/firestore"`. Also, the code above shows you using `import`, not `require()` so I'm not sure what you mean

Comment: What I mean by _"old"_ is that you used to use `import firebase from "firebase"` but that was quite a few major versions ago